# Japanese introduction speech help for an English Teacher

Tags: english-to-japanese

I am currently applying for a job teaching English in Japan, and one of the tasks is to introduce myself to the Japanese teachers at the school. It's basically a test in beginner Japanese. I have worked out most of my speech, but as I know very little Japanese, I would greatly appreciate it if someone who does know Japanese can check it is ok for me, and maybe alter it if some of the wording is wrong? As I have done it by myself. Also, I want to add an etra bit (where I have written "Insert Here") but do not know enough Japanese to translate this to say, and I feel that it would be pointless getting a garbled machine translation.

If anyone has the spare time, It would be a great assisstance to me if someone coul go through this a correct it for me. Thanks!

## Japanese:

> Konnichiwa Minna-san!
>   Watashi wa Trigg Matthew des, watashi wa eigo. Watashi ha suki hon, anime to bideo geimu. (Insert here) Watashi wa tanoshinoshitemasu goruden weiku, comiket anime expo, eto taberu daifuku ichigo. Yoroshkun gozaishimasu!

## English:

> Good afternoon, everyone!
>   My name is Matthew Trigg, I'm english. I like books, anime and video games. (insert here) I am looking forward to Golden week, Comiket anime expo and eating daifuku strawberries. Please take care of me!

Want to add (insert here) - I often reviewed and improved my friends' essays at University, and help them with spelling correction, grammar and the correct wording in sentence structure.

Comment: At the very least you should learn enough grammar to know that your sentences need to end in verbs. I'm afraid that what you have written is very wrong. Unfortunately, this is not a forum for proofreading/translation. If you have specific questions about particular aspects of grammar then by all means post those.

Comment: Ok, fair enough I thought this was for questions and answers, sorry if it was the wrong place to ask. thanks anyway!

Comment: Grammar aside, I thought I should point out that where you tried to say "I am English", the word you used, "eigo", refers to the English language, not to a person from England (the "go" at the end means "language"). If you are going to be teaching English, "eigo" is a good word for you to know, but it's not the one you want for that sentence :) See this to decide which word you do want: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25257/ Good luck!

Comment: It is not easy to work as an English teacher in formal schools in Japan. If you are not from an English speaking country, you will be prompted to submit a certificate showing your ability to teach English.

Comment: Lang-8.com might be a more suitable site for something like this. You practice writing entries in Japanese, and get corrected by native speakers of the language. In return, you correct entries written in English by people practicing that language.

Answer (score 1):

こんにちはみなさん。

トリッグマシューと申｛もう｝します。

イングランドから参｛まい｝りました。

本｛ほん｝を読｛よ｝むこととアニメを見｛み｝ることとゲームすることが好｛す｝きです。

コミケアニメエキスポに行こうと思っています。